# Changing setTimeout not working in React with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a postActions.js in my code where I write all my Redux action codes. 
One of the functions in it is a logout code.

This is the code.

```
export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expirationDate');
    return {
        type: AUTH_LOGOUT
    }
}
```

This logout action creator is called after an expiration time has reached. This is done using a setTimeout function like below.

```
export const checkAuthTimeout = expirationTime => {
    return dispatch => {
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(logout());
        }, expirationTime*1000);
    }
}
```

timeoutVar is declared in the top of the code, outside all the functions like this.

```
var timeoutVar;
```

Now here is my problem. Whenever a person is active in the app, I want to change setTimeout to a later time, so that he is not logged out when he is active. This is done with a code like this. logoutTime is the new time to be used for setTimeout.

```
clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(logoutTime));
```

For some reason, the above code is not changing setTimeout. Lets say logoutTime is 10, it is supposed to change setTimeout to happen 10 more seconds from now, but it does not change anything.

If I only use `clearTimeout(timeoutVar)`, the timer stops. 
That is working. But when I also use `dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(logoutTime))` the event happens at the old time itself. I am stuck with this for a long time. Please help.

Comment: `Whenever a person is active in the app` what does that mean? When the user moves the mouse, scrolls or types or do you mean when the user does something that fetches data?

Comment: Yeah. When a person does things like fetching data, so the clearTimeout code is kept in the actions where data is fetched. Also things like url changes, calling something from backend API .etc is considered person is active.  Moving mouse, scrolling .etc is not being active in my case.

Comment: @Adam Try to console.log the timeout ID you get back from calling setTimeout whenever the timeout is set or cleared, you will probably see what goes wrong.

Comment: @timotgl I just did it, here it is - https://imgur.com/a/N5RpmXX
That is the timeout ID after setting, after clearing, and after making a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Finally.

Since its React, my components were getting called multiple times and this triggered the setTimeout function multiple times. So there were multiple instances of setTimeout running. I had setTimeout called outside the function call like this -

```
clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(logoutTime));
```

But checkAuthTimeout was also getting called in other locations without clearTimeout due to some lifecycle methods without clearTimeout and this created many instances of setTimeout. Safest option is to move clearTimeout inside the function. Like this.

```
export const checkAuthTimeout = expirationTime => {
    return dispatch => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // ADD THIS JUST BEFORE SETTIMEOUT
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(logout());
        }, expirationTime*1000);
    }
}
```

I just had to add a clearTimeout just before setTimeout all the time.